# Solve equation to find two missing numbers in a sequence of positive integers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

This problem is inspired from an algorithm question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492302/easy-interview-question-got-harder-given-numbers-1-100-find-the-missing-numbe?rq=1.

**Summary of above thread:** Let's say that I am being given a sequence of positive integers. We are given the `min` and `max` of this sequence. I randomly delete two numbers. How do I find them.

What we could do is create two equations from two observations: for a given sequence, we know the sum and product of all numbers. Subtracting the sum and product of the sequence from known sum and product will yield two equations of the form:

$$
x*y = constant
$$

and

$$
x+y = constant
$$

Now, let's think about constraints.

1) x is a positive integer

2) y is a positive integer

3) $$x \neq y $$ because the two deleted numbers cannot be the same numbers.

Thus, I am trying to find the solution for $$x*y = x+y$$ with a constraint that $$x\neq y$$

Simplifying above equation, we get $$ 1/x + 1/y = 1$$

Now, one obvious solution is $$x = y = 2$$. However, we know that $$ x \neq y$$.

Hence, the big issue at hand is to solve above equation i.e. $$ 1/x + 1/y = 1$$ where `x and y are positive integers` and `x!=y`.

I tried using Desmos, but it wouldn't allow me to enter constraints properly. I'd appreciate any help. My hypothesis is that above equation has no solution.

---

Clarification: the numbers have to be greater than 0. i.e.

$$
x>0
$$
$$
y>0
$$

---

Example: 
Let's say we have ten numbers: 1 through 10.
I randomly delete, say, 4 and 6.
The objective is to find these two numbers.

We know that the sum of 1...10 should be 55, and the product of all numbers should be 3628800.

Now, the sum and product of numbers without 4 and 6 is: 45 and 151200.
So, we know that missing numbers' sum = 10 and product = 24. These are positive integers > 0. So, the values are 4 and 6.

Comment: $x= {{y} \over {y-1}}$

Comment: How about $x = \frac{1}{2}, y = -1$?

Comment: @Thanks. I think I need to clarify that numbers are greater than zero. I am sorry about this.

Comment: I am confused by the above part "I randomly delete two numbers. How do I find them" ?

Comment: @Peter: Let me add an example

Comment: @Peter: The numbers have to real integers > `0`. I think I have mentioned this as a constraint.

Comment: You mean "positive integers". In this case, there is actually no solution.

Comment: @Peter. Yes, I meant positive integers. I have corrected the entire post.

Comment: So, your object is to determine the two numbers when sum and product are given ?

Comment: @Peter. Yes, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to solve $$xy=a\\x+y=b$$ given $a,b$ in the positive integers, not $\frac 1x+\frac 1y=1$  You get $a,b$ from the sum and product as you say.  Because of the symmetry we can insist $y \ge x$ and you specify $x\neq y$.  You can proceed by substitution.
$$x=b-y\\y(b-y)=a\\y^2-by+a=0\\y=\frac 12\left(b+\sqrt{b^2-4a}\right)\\x=\frac 12\left(b-\sqrt{b^2-4a}\right)$$
where your condition $x \neq y$ will fail if $b^2=4a$

Comment: Thank you for your help. I like your approach. How do we factor that `x` and `y` are positive integers and not real numbers?

Comment: You just look to see if $x,y$ come out integers.  If they are not, you declare failure.  If the problem has been constructed as you say, they will be integers.

Comment: Thanks again, Ross. So, there is no way to know all positive integers that will satisfy above equation? I am guessing there are no such integers. If so, is there any way to prove this?

Comment: You need $b^2-4a$ to be a perfect square and $0 \lt 4a \lt b^2$.  Once you have that $x,y$ will come out distict positive integers. In your example, $b=10,a=24,b^2-4a=100-96=4$ so there is a solution.  It is easier to start with $x,y$ and compute $a,b$, but you can go the other way.

Comment: I know $225$ and $25$ are both squares, so $a=50, b=15$ will satisfy the requirement.  Then $x=\frac 12(15-\sqrt{225-200})=5$ and $y=10$

Answer (score 1):

To solve the system $$x+y=a$$ $$xy=b$$ insert $\ y=a-x\ $ into the second equation. This gives $$ax-x^2=b$$ hence $$x^2-ax+b=0$$

This is a quadratic equation you can easily solve. If both solutions are positive integers, you have found the numbers.